# Problem with installation of Xubuntu all versions except 10.04

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu

I'm trying to install a xubuntu version greater than 10.04, but it doesn't work.
I run the program via a usb stick. I can access to the menu just after I choose my keyboard. I choose "Install" or "Try Xubuntu without installing", then I get an error `set power failed status`. So I shutdown the PC and I re run the install program with `blacklist=firewire_ohci` in paramaters. I don't get the error anymore with this line. Xubuntu is loading and after a couple of seconds, the loader stops and doesn't continue.

I tried differents versions (12.04,13.04,15.10,16.04) but none of them work. I have an Acer Travelmate.